# Reduce exported .obj file size

Tags: objects, export

I am new to Blender, 
I have created a 3D object model for my project. My *.obj* file (exported from) Blender is too large, around 41 MB. How can I reduce its size? I have to use it in `three.js`
Since its size is too large, it is taking too much time to load.

Comment: the .obj exporter will apply modifiers to the mesh upon export unless you remove them or deactivate this setting when exporting.  For a file that size, I'd guess this there is a Sub-Surf or Multi-res assigned to the model.

Comment: Is the size caused by huge image textures or by geometry?

Comment: @stacker It's just a 3d object, I think you have to convert these to json for use in threejs iirc but the filesize will still be the same, possibly larger.

Comment: yes, its just a 3D object.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to reduce the number of polygons (vertices, edges and faces). My guess is that you have a pretty high poly model to generate a 41MB file.

One way to reduce a mesh's polygons is to use a *[Decimate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html)* modifier. Do note that you will have to apply the modifier before is takes effect on the export.

Answer (score 3):

These are the three steps i try using to reduce file size of my exported `*.obj`-files:

```
Modeling -> Vertex -> Remove double vertices
Modeling -> Mesh -> Clean up -> Delete loose
Modeling -> Mesh -> Clean up -> Decimate geometry -> Drag to desired 'percentage', e.g 0.5
```

[image: Loose and Decimate]
[image: Double verices]